# How Can I Add A Panel That Says "OK" and "Cancel" after clicking a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

So basically I have this button. (rightbutton)

I want it so when you click on this button a notification/popup appears that says "Congratulations, you clicked a button." then just say "OK" and "Cancel" (both just exit out the panel, same "task" really)

I used a JOptionPane but that of course would not work because it has a big text bar which I don't want.

So I'm guessing you'd have to make a JPanel and add the JButtons "OK" and "Cancel" inside that panel? I'm stumped.

```
rightbutton = new JButton("Right.");
    add(rightbutton);
    rightbutton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    //what do we want to happen when we
                    //click the button
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Congratulations, you clicked the button.");
```

thanks!

Comment: So you want just a panel with buttons an not frame?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the JOptionPane component by passing some arguments to it.

```
public static int showOptionDialog(Component parentComponent,
                               Object message,
                               String title,
                               int optionType,
                               int messageType,
                               Icon icon,
                               Object[] options,
                               Object initialValue)
                        throws HeadlessException


optionType
Defines the set of option buttons that appear at the bottom of the dialog box:
    DEFAULT_OPTION
    YES_NO_OPTION
    YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION
    OK_CANCEL_OPTION
```

Is OK_CANCEL_OPOTION what you want?

Answer (score 0):

try this it may help

```
rightbutton = new JButton("Right.");
close = new JButton("close.");
    add(rightbutton);
    add(close)
    rightbutton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    //what do we want to happen when we
                    //click the button
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Congratulations, you clicked t
                        }

    close.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    //what do we want to happen when we
                    //click the button
                                  int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Do you want to  close","Warning",dialogButton);

                if(dialogButton == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){ //The ISSUE is here
                        System.exit(0);
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to hide JOptionPane's title bar.It is not ok.But by using "Popup" window,it will help you to get what you want.I try to use it,"Popup".It works well.Code is here.

```
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Popup;
import javax.swing.PopupFactory;

public class SwingTest extends JFrame{
    JButton rightbutton,btnOk,btnCancel;
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel lblMsg;
    Popup popup;
    public SwingTest(){
        setSize(300,300);
        rightbutton=new JButton("Right");
        rightbutton.setBounds(100, 100, 80, 30);
        //Message you want to show
        lblMsg=new JLabel("Congratulations, you clicked the button.");
        lblMsg.setBounds(30, 30, 200, 18);
        btnOk=new JButton("Ok");
        btnOk.setBounds(30, 60, 30, 30);
        btnCancel=new JButton("Cancel");
        btnCancel.setBounds(70, 60, 80, 30);

        panel=new JPanel();
        panel.setSize(250,200);
        panel.add(lblMsg);
        panel.add(btnOk);
        panel.add(btnCancel);

        //Create Popup
        PopupFactory factory=PopupFactory.getSharedInstance();
        popup=factory.getPopup(this, panel, 100, 100);

        add(rightbutton);
        rightbutton.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                       popup.show();
                    }
                });


        btnOk.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                       popup.hide();
                    }
                });
        btnCancel.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                       popup.hide();
                    }
                });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SwingTest().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

May this code be a part of that you want.Thanks